# Remote Execute the legacy tool in another machine via SSH vs TCP/IP vs RPC vs others

Tags: java, ssh, tcp, network-programming

We have a Java web application which collects the inputs from the user and executes the legacy simulation tools in a remote machine by sharing the inputs in the JSON files.

The simulation tools doesn't have the option to run via HTTP request, therefore we have opted SSH. But there are some bottlenecks as below per the current design,

1. In order to avoid the manual steps of SSH authentication by keys/password, we have implemented Kerberos ticket based authentication which breaks often when windows updates, user changes the password and some other scenarios
2. Input and results are in JSON file formats in specified directories and each workflows will process it based on workflows the worflow id's matches with the directory name
3. Monitoring is the very tedious task as per current design. Because few of the workflows run for hours-days. So we need to update the application with the current status as Running-UpToDate-Compeleted/Error. Workflow will be running in commandline mode, it will update the logs/progress from remote system to server machine via SSH and we write this content into files. once user clicks on Refresh button, Application checks the progress file in specific directory and update the status. But it involves additional steps to get the current status and also it is slow because it involves file operation and copying from one machine to another.
4. Is there anyway we could optimize our design?

> Also I found the other options like TCP/IP and RPC. To communicate with Remote systems and trigger the workflow. Our application is Spring boot/React web based, is it fine to mix http and TCP/IP in single application?

We are using Waffle SSO with Spring security, how to implement TCP/IP without compromising security.

Comment: The first improvement you can make is to use [public key auth](https://woshub.com/using-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-windows/)

Comment: We have around 50 users , there are 5 machine involved in workflow execution. one server and 4 remote workstations. Generating and maintaining Private/Public keys are not so efficient for multiple machines. That's why we have automated the SSH authentication process by Kerberos ticket (GSSAPI).

Comment: Ah OK. But that's not so good if updates break it. You might want to look into why that's happening and how to stop it

Comment: Yep Sure. Do you have any suggestion for the monitoring? Few workflows runs for few hours and it shares the progress/logs through CMD/PowerShell via SSH from remote workstation to the server . From the console progress data are redirected to the file. If the user clicks on refresh button in UI, Java application checks for the status and errors in different files and updates it in the DB. Is there any scope for improvement.  I just read about TCP/IP to establish the connection with workstation and listen to the  logs, once it completes Java can directly update the status as Completed/Error.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with the Windows sysadmin stuff